# GHC evaluation strategy

Tags: haskell, ghc, lazy-evaluation

I'm a little confused with how the following code executes when compiled with GHC 7.6.3

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

main = do let m1 = M.fromList $ zip [1..10000000] [1..]
          putStrLn $ "Value = " ++ (show $ M.map (+2) m1 M.! 555)
```

Compiled with `ghc --make -O3`, it gets me the following result:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ./MapLazy
Value = 557
29.88user 2.16system 0:32.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2140348maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+535227minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Yet, if I change it to just `show $ m1 M.! 555`, I get *much* lower memory usage, yet takes almost the same time:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ./MapLazy
555
23.82user 1.17system 0:25.06elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1192100maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+298165minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

What's actually happening here? Does the entire Map get instantiated just because I read out a single value? Could I have prevented that somehow? I mean, it's a binary search tree, so I was expecting just the one path I looked up on the new map to be actually evaluated.

Comment: `Map` is spine strict... and if you think about it, you'll see why it would be sort of hard for it not to be.

Comment: Why does it require spine-strict-ness? Like I said in my question, I was really expecting it to just evaluate that one path from root to leaf. That should be doable in O(log n), right?

Comment: @Savui: remember that maps are size-balanced binary trees.  I believe it's the rebalancing that forces spine strictness.

Comment: @JohnL: No, this doesn't make sense, specially when it comes to Data.Map.map. That function requires no rebalancing: it takes a balanced tree and produces another one with identical structure.

Comment: @Savui: if `Data.Map.map` were completely lazy, it would create thunks that would have to reference the original structure.  So long as the map creation is spine-strict, the full map will be instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it. Let's look at the source for `Data.Map.map`.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
map f m
  = mapWithKey (\_ x -> f x) m

mapWithKey :: (k -> a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
mapWithKey _ Tip = Tip
mapWithKey f (Bin sx kx x l r) 
  = Bin sx kx (f kx x) (mapWithKey f l) (mapWithKey f r)
```

Now, `mapWithKey` seems to build just the top constructor of the tree and lazily recursing for the two branches... but:

```
data Map k a  = Tip 
              | Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
```

Above we see that the subtrees are strict fields! So the recursive calls to `mapWithKey` will be forced, causing the full tree to be updated strictly instead of lazily.

Comment: This is what I missed. I went through the sources for mapWithKey before posting the question, but didn't pay attention to the data Map declaration. Thanks!

Follow up question: is there a reason why such strictness is considered a good thing? Is there a post somewhere on GHC mailing list where they had a discussion about this?

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, the more it seems like a Map is the one great example where laziness would actually not be a bad thing. Can't see why they made it spine-strict.